# Update into a MySQL table unless same value already exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a row in a database but I want it to not update if the value already exists.

For example:

```
UPDATE religion SET
        name='3'
        WHERE id=4
        AND id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM religion);
```

I was trying to do data validation. I wanted to make it so that the table would not update if the value inputted already exists in the table.

Comment: It is very unclear what your try to achive

Comment: `UPDATE religion SET
        name='3'
        WHERE id=4
        AND name!='3';
`  Do you want this?

Comment: You need to clarify your goal here.  Your example query tries to update only rows that do not exist in the table.  Which doesn't make sense.  Are you trying to add a new row to the table?  In that case, use `insert`.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Are you trying to say only update the `name` column when the `id` column is not yet set (i.e., `id` == `NULL`)? It would make more sense if you updated `name` when `name` is not set.

Comment: I was trying to do data validation. I wanted to make it so that the table would not update if the value inputted already exists in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE religion SET name='3' WHERE id = 4 AND name = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after a insert statement not an update statement. Because you can't update a row if it doesn't exists. So I would think that you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO religion
(
    id,
    name
)
SELECT
    tbl.Id,
    tbl.`name`
FROM
    (
        SELECT 4 as Id, '3' as name
    ) as tbl
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM religion WHERE religion.id=tbl.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `UPDATE religion SET name='3' WHERE id=4 AND name!='3';`
Here is a simple explanation: If the id is equal to 4 and the name is not equal to 3, update. This works.